# difference between two multi-byte integers, big endian and little endian

Tags: c, algorithm, endianness

if I have 4 multi-byte integers, A, B, C, D in a big endian system

and A-B = C-D

if they are in a little endian system, does the equality still hold?

Note: I want to get the difference between numbers which are received from network, so they are in network order or host order.

Comment: Yes. Of course. The mathematical operators will work on the multi-byte integers in the correct way for the platform.

Comment: You mean if the same bit-pattern is interpreted as little-endian integers? The equality need not hold then.

Answer (score 8):

Endianness is only about the computer's representation of the numbers, not the values. The value is independent of endianness,<sup>1</sup> so the equality holds.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Unless, of course, the bytes are incorrectly interpreted. This can happen, for example, when a big-endian system writes some bytes to the network and a little-endian system on the receiving side interprets them as little-endian.</sub>

Comment: "Unless, of course, the bytes are incorrectly interpreted" -- This is why we have `ntohl()` and `htonl()` functions.